# Ordenar o resultado de uma busca com filtro

Tags: laravel

Tenho uma busca no site e eu posso optar por diversos filtros e isso já funciona me retornando e fazendo a paginação corretamente.

**Exemplo:**

> `/empresas?estado=2&tipo=3&page=2`

O problema é quando eu clico em ordenar por um `select form`, ele não mantém a `URL` atual, ele simplesmente faz:

> `/empresas?ordenar=nome`

Deveria ser algo do tipo:

> /empresas?estado=2&tipo=3&ordenar=nome&page=3

Fiz um `append`, como a paginação faz, mas, mesmo assim não deu certo.

No `Controller`:

```
$estados = DB::table('estados')->orderBy('nome', 'asc')->get();
$tipos = DB::table('tipos')->orderBy('nome', 'asc')->get();

$word = Input::get('query');
$ordenar = Input::get('ordenar');
$estado = Input::get('estado');
$tipo = Input::get('tipo');

$query = Empresas::with('usuario')->with('estado');

if($word)
    $query->where('descricao', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
          ->orWhere('carta', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%');

if($estado)
    $query->whereIn('estado_id', $estado);

if($tipo)
    $query->where('tipo_id', $tipo);

if($ordenar)
    $query->orderby($ordenar, 'asc');

$empresas = $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(18);

return view("pages.empresas.index")
        ->with('estados', $estados)
        ->with('tipos', $tipos)
        ->with(compact('empresas', 'word', 'ordenar', 'estado','tipo'));
```

Na `View`:

Eu faco um `foreach` trazendo os campos normalmente e faco o `append` com o render que já funciona

```
<center>
     {!! str_replace('/?','?', $empresas->appends(Input::query())->render()) !!}    
</center>
```

E tenho um formulario para ordenacao, talvez o erro esteja nele

```
<form action="/empresas" method="get">
    <select class="form-control m-b" name="ordenar" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Ordenar por...</option>
       <option value="nome">Nome</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Poste seu código.

Comment: É que seu `combobox` não está renderizado conforme o Laravel, certo ?

Comment: Exatamente, e nao sei como colocar ele no append

Comment: Acho que seria o caso de conseguir jogar os "GETs" atuais no action do form, não? Tipo action="/empresas?estado=2&tipo=3". Será que isso funciona?

Comment: Nao funciona :(  varios sites possui esse "ordenar"  mas nao consigo procurar, nao sei o nome especifico. Provavel que tenha algum pacote, ou algo parecido..  mas ta dificil achar.. rs

Alguem tem alguma luz, ao caminho preu seguir?

obrigado

Comment: Você tem que adicionar os parâmetros atuais (que estão na url atual) na action de seu form, ou adicionar inputs do tipo hidden com os parâmetros da url atual em seu form.

Comment: @EduardoCruz resolvido. Dá uma olhada na minha resposta :). Mesmo que tenha arrumado outra solução, talvez valha a pena olhar, como aprendizado

Comment: Qual é a versão que está usando Laravel 4 ou Laravel 5?

Answer (score 1):

Já entendi o que está acontecendo. Como você está usando o formulário, apenas os dados presentes nesse formulário é os que serão enviados para a `URL`.

Geralmente eu não costumo usar formulários para criar `Ordenação`, mas apenas Links  no cabeçalhos das tabelas.

Creio que uma forma de resolver isso é incluindo as querystrings anteriores num `input:hidden` nesse formulário.

```
<form action="/empresas" method=get>
     <select class="form-control m-b" name="ordenar" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Ordenar por...</option>
     <option value="nome">Nome</option>                                                       
     </select>

     @foreach(Input::except('ordenar') as $name => $value)
         {{ Form::hidden($name, $value) }}
     @endforeach

</form>
```

Exemplo: